# Single quotes included in shell output when enabling set -x

Tags: shell

I am having trouble while using `set -x`.

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x

while getopts c:a: optionalargs
do
        case $optionalargs in
          c)copt=$OPTARG;;
          a)aopt=$OPTARG;;
          *)echo "Invalid arg";;
        esac
done

if [ ! -z "$copt" ]
then
    export CHAR_SET=$copt
fi

if [ ! -z "$aopt" ]
then
    export ADDITIONAL_FLAGS=$aopt
fi

shift $((OPTIND -1))

echo OP_C = "${CHAR_SET}"
echo OP_A = "${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}"
```

**Results:**

when using `set -x`

```
./a.sh -a additional -c character
OP_C = 'character'
OP_A = 'additional'
```

Commenting out `set -x`

```
./a.sh -a additional -c character
OP_C = character
OP_A = additional
```

**Question:**

Why the single quotes is being included in the results when enabling `set -x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce. This is the output I get from my /bin/sh with `set -x` enabled:

```
+ getopts c:a: optionalargs
+ case $optionalargs in
+ aopt=additional
+ getopts c:a: optionalargs
+ case $optionalargs in
+ copt=character
+ getopts c:a: optionalargs
+ '[' '!' -z character ']'
+ export CHAR_SET=character
+ CHAR_SET=character
+ '[' '!' -z additional ']'
+ export ADDITIONAL_FLAGS=additional
+ ADDITIONAL_FLAGS=additional
+ shift 4
+ echo OP_C = character
OP_C = character
+ echo OP_A = additional
OP_A = additional
```

I also tried it with *dash* and *ash*, same result.